# What's a good way to create a string array in Ruby based on integer variables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

The integer variables are:

```
toonie = 2, loonie = 1, quarter = 1, dime = 0, nickel = 1, penny = 3
```

I want the final output to be

```
"2 toonies, 1 loonie, 1 quarter, 1 nickel, 3 pennies"
```

Is there a way to interpolate this all from Ruby code inside [] array brackets and then add .join(", ")?

Or will I have to declare an empty array first, and then write some Ruby code to add to the array if the integer variable is greater than 0?

Comment: Why do you have single variables in the first place, is it an option to store the values in a hash?

Comment: @spickermann You're right. It must be Friday, or I'm a newbie. I'm going to go with both, and also use a hash instead as others suggested in their answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
coins = { toonie: 2, loonie: 1, quarter: 1, dime: 0, nickel: 1, penny: 3 }
coins.map { |k, v| pluralize(v, k) if v > 0 }.compact.join(', ')
#=> "2 toonie, 1 loonie, 1 quarter, 1 nickel, 3 penny"
```

Note that [`pluralize`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-pluralize) is a `ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper` method. Therefore it is only available in views and helpers.

When you want to use your example outside of views, you might want to use [`pluralize`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-pluralize) from `ActiveSupport` instead - what makes the solution slightly longer:

```
coins.map { |k, v| "#{v} #{v == 1 ? k : k.pluralize}" if v > 0 }.compact.join(', ')
#=> "2 toonie, 1 loonie, 1 quarter, 1 nickel, 3 penny"
```

Comment: It's worth noting that there's a [`pluralize`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-pluralize) method takes arguments that do the `== 1` comparison for you: `pluralize(coins[:quarter], 'quarter')`.

Comment: @tadman: There are two different versions of the `pluralize` method. The one from `ActionView` does, the one from `ActiveSupport` doesn't. I used both versions in my answer, please note the difference between both examples.

Comment: Right! I didn't see the first one since it's buried in a pretty gnarly one-liner, but there it is. Worth explaining there's actually two different methods that are similar in output, yet one's part of String and the other isn't.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly you're looking for, but I would start with a hash like:

```
coins = {"toonie" => 2, "loonie" => 1, "quarter" => 1, "dime" => 0, "nickel" => 1, "penny" => 3}
```

then you can use this to print the counts

```
def coin_counts(coins)
  (coins.keys.select { |coin| coins[coin] > 0}.map {|coin| coins[coin].to_s + " " + coin}).join(", ")
end
```

If you would like appropriate pluralizing, you can do the following:

```
include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper
def coin_counts(coins)
  (coins.keys.select { |coin| coins[coin] > 0}.map {|coin| pluralize(coins[coin], coin)}).join(", ")
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Can be done in rails:

```
hash = {
  "toonie" => 2,
  "loonie" => 1,
  "quarter" => 1,
  "dime" => 0,
  "nickel" => 1,
  "penny" => 3
}

hash.to_a.map { |ele| "#{ele.last} #{ele.last> 1 ? ele.first.pluralize : ele.first}" }.join(", ")
```

Basically what you do is convert the hash to an array, which will look like this:

```
[["toonie", 2], ["loonie", 1], ["quarter", 1], ["dime", 0], ["nickel", 1], ["penny", 3]]
```

Then you map each element to the function provided, which takes the inner array, takes the numeric value in the last entry, places it in a string and then adds the plural or singular value based on the numeric value you just checked. And finally merge it all together

```
=> "2 toonies, 1 loonie, 1 quarter, 1 nickel, 3 pennies"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just for fun and **should not be used in production** but you can achieve it like

```
def run
  toonie = 2
  loonie = 1
  quarter = 1
  dime = 0
  nickel = 1
  penny = 3

  Kernel::local_variables.each_with_object([]) { |var, array|
   next if eval(var.to_s).to_i.zero?
   array << "#{eval(var.to_s)} #{var}"
  }.join(', ')
end

run # returns "2 toonie, 1 loonie, 1 quarter, 1 nickel, 3 penny"
```

The above does not implement the pluralization requirement because it really depends if you will have irregular plural nouns or whatever.
I would go with a hash solution as described in the other answers

Comment: I'm feeling more than a little mortified you'd put `eval` in an example for beginners. This is the nuclear weapons approach. Every other answer uses a Hash, because that's the best plan here.

Comment: @tadman: especially since we have `Binding#local_variable_get` for exactly this use case.

Comment: `local_variable_get` is also super smelly in production code. They're a big clue that you need to rethink your implementation.

Comment: at what point did I say that it should be used in production? Showing the language's capabilities, albeit a bad one in the case, shouldn't be considered a nuclear disaster. Not only I suggested for it to NOT be used in production but I also recommended a hash approach from one of the other answers

Comment: @JörgWMittag didn't know about `Binding#local_variable_get`! Thanks